# Ghost external drive in disk utility

Tags: macos, disk-utility

[image][image]I noticed recently when I open up disk utility and I see my external hard drive show up even though nothing is connected to my Mac. I can't unmount it and it does not do anything. Just wondering, is this just a bug in my system or is there something wrong with my Mac?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you're seeing?  Disk Utility doesn't show drives it's not aware of.

Comment: Disk Utility will often show disk images, if you hover over the icon in Disk Utility you get a little "Eject" icon. Is that what you are seeing? Like @Allan said, post a screen capture to your question, otherwise this is a bit of a crap shoot...

Comment: This is what shows up in my disk utility even though nothing is connected to my mac at the time and pressing the eject button does not do anything.

Comment: Very interesting. Since the drive is called TimeMachine (I guess) this does not seem like a disk image. Yet that would imply that an actual drive is connected to your system.

Comment: nothing is connected to my mac at the time but when I connect a external drive to my mac another tab will appear with the drive but that one shows that it is mounted and ready to use.

Comment: To which disk are you referring?  You've selected an internal disk, but referencing an external.  If it's the external, please select it as we can't see what's being displayed.  Also, please post the output of the command `diskutil list` to your question.  Finally, @ us in comments so we're notified when you make updates.

Comment: Hi @Allan, I have made the changes and included the pictures that you requested.

Comment: @Allan any help for this?

Comment: Looking at the last screen, `diskutil` is seeing a physically attached drive (`/dev/disk2`).  If "nothing's connected" then either something is hung up with the kext that recognizes usb drives that it didn't release it, or something is still connected.  Please do two things reboot and see if it's still there and second, issue the command `diskutil info disk2`